# Html.BeginForm is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I want to take textbox value and i will download an excel list according to that value. This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadAttendeeExcel", "Attendee", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "downloadAttendee", @class = "stdform" }))
 {        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventID, new { id = "eventID" })
        </div>       
       <div>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventName, new { id = "eventName" })
        </div>

 }
```

This is my action but i can't set model.eventID according to textbox value and i can't understand why.

```
public ActionResult DownloadAttendeeExcel(AttendeeListItem model)
        {
            Reservation res = new Reservation();
            res.EventID = model.EventID;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You can't set values on `BeginForm`, instead you need to use `HiddenFor` or other Input Html elements.  This is because ONLY input elements are sent back on postback.

Comment: Hidden is not needed, your textbox should work fine. Is your view using the Model AttendeeListItem? Top of the view should have @model AttendeeListItem. Also : is EventName coming through and EventID not?

Comment: Also : are you using a normal submit button or performing an ajax call based on your form data?

Comment: I have model in my view. I get autocomplete eventnames with ajax so events are coming but my textbox value is not posting to model.EventID

Comment: <a class="btn" type="button" id="downloadAttendees" href="@Url.Action("DownloadAttendeeExcel", "Attendee")" style="width: 150px;"> is my button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button :

```
<a class="btn" type="button" id="downloadAttendees" ref="@Url.Action("DownloadAttendeeExcel", "Attendee")" style="width: 150px;">
```

Will perform an HttpGet and will not post your form data.
The simplest way to instruct your form to submit it's content(all the input fields it contains) is to use a html submit button :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```